# Restrict Spring Boot Application in wso2 Oauth

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have created a simple spring boot project which is generate some unique id whenever user access app. Now I want to protect the app resource with oauth.
My requirement is when user logged in with wso2is server it'll generate access token with that access token user can able to access the spring boot app to generate the key. 
Please Help me

Comment: So the basic requirement is to allow users with a valid access token to access the app and those who don't have one to redirect to IS and get a valid one?

Answer (score 0):

Article [1] explains how you can achieve this using an ESB and IS. Instead of an ESB, you can write a simple tomcat valve/filter which can do the same function done by the ESB in [1].

I have a sample implementation of a tomcat valve that protects a REST service with OAuth[2]. You can use that as a starting point and modify to your requirements.

[1] http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/02/securing-your-web-service-with-oauth2-using-wso2-identity-server-1/

[2] https://github.com/mefarazath/carbon-identity/blob/gsoc-uma/components/tomcat-valve/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/tomcat/valve/OAuthAccessTokenValidatorValve.java

Comment: I have an application which is running on tomcat, and user can able to access through REST call, now I want to restrict them. Like if user have access token then only they can able to access it. So I have to use API Manager for restriction or some other way is there?

Comment: No need simply you can talk to the TokenValidation and see if the token is valid. That is exactly what i have done in [2] check out the code :)

Comment: whatever code you have done in [2], I have to write it into my app or it'll be separate?

Comment: no you don't have to write that into the app, it's a tomcat valve you configure and use it externally to your app

Comment: can you please explain, how I can use it in my app??

Comment: hello @farasath please provide me steps how to achieve, in my application when user hit localhost:8080/generateKey it's going to generate unique key each time but I want to protect this url with wso2 oauth. where I can provide client secrete and client key so that it generate access token and user can able to access it. what changes I have to do in Tomcat Valve class. Please assist.